# Ubuntu 16: Change date on file/folder when moved - how?

Tags: 16.04, server

I got a server with two shares.
One is for active stuff, the other is inactive stuff, a script searches for folder/files older than a month and moves them to the archive.

The archive is read only, but when I move something old to the active stuff the date doesn't change so the folder/files and automatic moved to archive during the night.

How should I fix this? Somekind of trigger on the active folder to touch the stuff I move? Or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger you are looking for is the `touch` command. Simply `touch` every file that you move to the live archive and it gets the current access and modification date and time.

With the knowledge given by the OP's comment to this answer, another idea for a script:

- loop through all files of the active folder:
- if the file is also in the archive folder with the same change date, then `touch` it in the active folder.

By touching only the files who have a counterpart with the same date in the archive folder, you allow the files that have been moved back, to begin aging again after their first discovery. (Each moved file will only be touched once.)

I hope that I have made me clear.

Comment: Well when I discover a "new" file in the folder touch is it, yes. But how do I discover that a new folder/file has been added to a folder?

Comment: I understood that you are moving 'old' files back from the archive to the 'active' folder, selecting them by some kind of script. So every time you move one such file, you touch it to 'renew' it. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Yes but that is due to lack of information.
The moving part happens at the clients GUI, they drag and drop folder/files from archive to active.
On the Active folder I'd like to have 2 scripts, one that move older stuff to archive, and anther that touch'es the moved files so that they stay in the active folder.

Comment: I have edited my answer with this additional knowledge.